# Spring Boot REST API - Type mismatch on field ID

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, kotlin

I am new to Spring Boot with Kotlin and I am trying to implement a simple REST API with a MySQL database in the background. I started by creating a "TestEntity" class with a "TestEntityRepository", "TestEntityResource" and "TestEntityService". Everything worked fine until this point. I was able to POST and GET the data via the REST API.

After that I created another Entity "User" for which I wanted to do the same as for my TestEntity. I created the class with some more fields followed by the Repository, Resource and Service classes. Now, when I try to POST a new entry to my UserResource REST endpoint I get a 400 Bad Request error with the following message:

> Field error in object 'user' on field 'id': rejected value [null]; codes [typeMismatch.user.id,typeMismatch.id,typeMismatch.long,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [user.id,id]; arguments []; default message [id]]; default message [Failed to convert value of type 'null' to required type 'long'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [null] to type [@javax.persistence.Id @javax.persistence.GeneratedValue long] for value 'null'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A null value cannot be assigned to a primitive type]]

My User class looks like the following:

```
@Entity
class User(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val id: Long,

    @Column(name = "login_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    val loginId: String,

    @Column(name = "display_name")
    val displayName: String,

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_date")
    val createdDate: Date,

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "modify_date")
    val modifyDate: Date
)
```

The repository class looks like this:

```
@Repository
interface UserRepository: JpaRepository<User, Long>
```

The service class like this:

```
@Service
class UserService(val repo: UserRepository) {

    fun findAll(): List<User> = repo.findAll()

    fun findById(userId: Long): User = repo.findById(userId)
        .orElseThrow { ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "No user was found with this ID.") }

    fun post(user: User) {
        repo.save(user)
    }

    fun delete(user: User) {
        repo.delete(user)
    }
}
```

And finally my resource class (RestController) like this:

```
@RestController
class UserResource(val service: UserService) {

    @GetMapping("/user")
    fun get(): List<User> = service.findAll()

    @GetMapping("/user/{id}")
    fun get(@PathVariable(name = "id") id: Long): User = service.findById(id)

    @PostMapping("/user")
    fun post(user: User) {
        service.post(user)
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/user")
    fun delete(user: User) = service.delete(user)
}
```

Does anybody may have an idea what is going wrong? I am just sending a HTTP POST with a JSON object that contains the fields "loginId" and "displayName". The "id" field should be filled automatically but it does not work. Also when I add a field called "id" to my JSON the request will not be accepted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure `auto_increement` is set to `id` column in your table.
2. Use Autogeneration Strategy as `GenerationType.IDENTITY`.

Comment: How do I set auto_increment to my table? The Spring Framework does create it automatically, so I did nothing to create the database. I only wrote the connection parameters to my application properties file.

Comment: Then try using Generation Strategy as GenerationType.SEQUENCE. I guess this should work.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I tried all types of GenerationType. The error still happens...

Comment: Not sure if this works. Create separate class UserDTO. Add all the fields except the Id field, without any annotation. Now use this class to accept the request. Then manually covert this to User class by setting User fields individually. Then pass User object to service method. And make sure to rerun your project.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found a way to fix it but I am not sure if its the best way to do.

In my entity class I had to declare the createdDate and modifyDate fields as nullable:

```
@Entity
class User(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    var id: Long,

    @Column(name = "login_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    var loginId: String,

    @GeneratedValue(generator = APITokenGenerator.GENERATOR_NAME)
    @GenericGenerator(name = APITokenGenerator.GENERATOR_NAME, strategy = "my.package.name.APITokenGenerator")
    @Column(name = "api_token")
    var apiToken: String? = null,

    @Column(name = "display_name")
    var displayName: String,

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_date")
    var createdDate: Date? = null,

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "modify_date")
    var modifyDate: Date? = null
)
```

But I think the most important thing was to add the @RequestBody annotation to my RestController class which handles the incoming requests:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
class UserResource(val service: UserService) {

    @GetMapping()
    fun get(): List<User> = service.findAll()

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    fun get(@PathVariable(name = "id") id: Long): User = service.findById(id)

    @PostMapping()
    fun post(@RequestBody user: User) {
        service.post(user)
    }

    @DeleteMapping("")
    fun delete(@RequestBody user: User) = service.delete(user)
}
```

It would be nice if someone can answer me if this is the correct solution or if there is something not correct anyway :-)